# Can I say that if a set is infinite and does not have same cardinality as the set of natural numbers, then the set is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

From the book $\mathbf{A~Readable~Introduction~to~Real~Mathematics}$ by Daniel, David, Peter Rosenthal.

Definition 10.2.1. A set is countable (sometimes called denumerable, or
enumerable) if it is either finite or has the same cardinality as the set of natural numbers. A set is said to be uncountable if it is not countable.

but I don't know wheather the statement if a set is infinite and does not have same cardinality as the set of natural numbers, then the set is uncountable holds as well ?

I know the Definition can not imply the statement I give.
But I am just quite curious on the truth of the statement I provide above.

Comment: the definition of an uncountable set is "an infinite set that is not less than or equal to the natural numbers" so a set defined such that it is infinite and not equal or less than the cardinality of the natural numbers is uncountable **by definition**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes an infinite set that has a cardinality that is not equal to the natural numbers is uncountable.